# Delete blank line at the top of email

Tags: vba, outlook

I hired someone to write code which does the following when an email is highlighted.

FW Email
Insert already copied item from clipboard and paste in To Field (the copied email address)
Remove FW: from Subject line
Remove everything above the original message which includes the original email info/date/address etc.

It leaves a blank line above the first word of the body which is "Hello Name".

How can I delete that empty row so "Hello Name" is at the top of the email OR delete the "Hello Name" alltogether?

```vb
Sub ForwardFromClipboard2()
    
    Dim tmpEmail As MailItem
    Dim fwEmail As MailItem    
    
    For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            
            Set tmpEmail = Item.Forward
            tmpEmail.Subject = Item.Subject
            tmpEmail.To = GetClipBoardText
            
            tmpEmail.Display
            RemoveSign (tmpEmail.Subject)
            
            Set tmpEmail = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
    
Sub RemoveSign(MySubject As String)
    Dim objOL As Application
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objSel As Object
    
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set objSel = objDoc.Application.Selection
        
    ' delete signature
    If objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailOriginal") Then
        Set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailOriginal")
        objSel.Start = 0
        objSel.End = objBkm.Start
        objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
    End If
    
    ' delete FROM:, TO:, SUBJECT:
    Dim search As String
    search = "Subject:"
    Dim search2 As String
    search2 = MySubject
    
    For Each para In objDoc.Paragraphs
    
        Dim txt As String
        txt = para.Range.Text
    
        If InStr(txt, search) Or InStr(txt, search2) Then
            para.Range.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    
    Next
End Sub
    
Function GetClipBoardText() As String
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    
    myString = DataObj.GetText(1)
    GetClipBoardText = myString
    
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    GetClipBoardText = ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HTMLBody` or the Word object model to edit the message body according to your needs. The Word object model provides the `Delete` method of the `Range` class which deletes the specified number of characters or words. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.